# Memory allocation problem when creating a class C++

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

Still learning C++, and still having specific errors :). I have an object of the following composition:

```
class document {
private:
    char *denumire;
    char *tema;
    char *autorul;
    int num_pag;
    data last_edit;
public:
    document();
    document (const char *s1,const char *s2,const char *s3, int i1, data d1);
    document (const document&);
    document (const char *s1);
    ~document ();
    void printdoc(void);
    void chden(char *s);
    void chtema(char *s);
    void chaut(char *s);
    void chnumpag(int n);
    void chdata(data d);
};
```

The problem is that when I try to initialize it with the following constructor, I get segmentation fault:

```
document::document (char *s1, char *s2, char *s3, int i1, data d1) {
    denumire=new char[strlen(s1)+1];
    strcpy(denumire,s1);
    tema=new char[strlen(s2)+1];
    strcpy(tema,s2);
    autorul=new char[strlen(s3)+1];
    strcpy(autorul,s3);
    num_pag=i1;
    last_edit.an=d1.an;
    last_edit.luna=d1.luna;
    last_edit.zi=d1.zi;
    cout <<"Setarea documentului finisata\n";
}
```

As much as I understand, all the variables are assigned correctly, because the message "Setarea documentului finisata" appears, and after that the segfault appears. All the code compiles fine, without any warnings. 
Also, I tried to search for something on Google, but couldn't find situations similar to mine. What could be the cause of such strange behaviour?

PS: The implementation of the copy constructor:

```
document::document (const document& a) :
    denumire(new char [strlen(a.denumire)+1]),
    tema(new char[strlen(a.tema)+1]),
    autorul(new char[strlen(a.autorul)+1]),
    num_pag(a.num_pag),
    last_edit(a.last_edit)
{
    strcpy(denumire,a.denumire);
    strcpy(tema,a.tema);
    strcpy(autorul,a.autorul);
}
```

I took it from a teacher's examples. Also, I initialise the variables in the following way:

```
document c(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str(),s3.c_str(),i1,d1)
```

because the teacher requires us that the object contains dinamically created strings :)

Comment: Don't use new char[] , use std::string.

Comment: Well the problem is not in that code if it gets to the end of it.  Plug a debugger into it and see where exactly it crashes.  Most likely you are overwriting some memory elsewhere and this is causing the memory allocation to die.

Comment: General remark: Since this is C++, use `std::string` to represent strings, not a `char *`. Also, initialize your members in the initialization-list of the constructor, and not in the body.

Comment: @Ion : Can you please edit your post to show the implementation of the class' copy constructor? Also, does your class also have a custom copy assignment operator? If not, you may be corrupting memory by doing a double-`delete` on your `char*`s.

Comment: unapersson, Space_C0wb0y, I also don't like the idea of using C-type strings, but the teacher to whom I have to give this piece of code requires using manually alocated strings :(
I try to use C++-style strings in the main(), but when transferring them to the function, I transform them to a const char* and after that strcpy that into the objects :)

Comment: @Ion Get a new teacher - anyone that makes you use char * is not fit to teach anything about C++.

Comment: @Ion: Also, homework-question should be tagged as such.

Comment: @Ion when you are using memory directly as here you have to watch for the rule-of-three (and c++0x four-and-a-half, as i have seen it called in SO). That means  you need a copy-constructor and an assignment operator and a destructor. If you don't have those you will end up with broken pointers and doing double deletes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I figured out where was the error, a debugger showed that it would be in the next function... Still, between those two functions I printed some text, but that text wasn't showing up...
Also, I have another question: when initializing an object from that class with no parameters, I initialised the strings from within with '\0', now I cannot print them, when I output them to cout, it stops at the first '\0'. What is the best way to print an empty string?

Comment: Standard output is buffered, so when you write to cout it won't necessarily write to console at that exact point. You can call cout.flush(); to force it to write output immediately.

Comment: You could write your own minimal string class - then at least you don't have to repeat everything 3 times, while obeying the letter of the law. Also you'd then be able to test that class separately.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure about what exactly is the problem but can give you some pointers. A segmentation fault occurs due to the following reasons:
1) You try to access a memory area that is not in the address space of the process
2) You try to use an uninitialized pointer

By address space, I mean the memory allocated to the process in the RAM

Hope it helps